# Using github with secret keys

Tags: python, github

I have a Python script with secret keys for the Tweeter API. I would like to version control my script using Github. How do I keep my keys secret while still uploading to Github? That is, the values of these

```
KEY = ""
KEY_SECRET = ""
TOKEN = ""
TOKEN_SECRET = ""
```

should be kept secret. Maybe I can put them in another file and load them, but .gitignor'ing said file? What is the correct pattern?

Comment: What you said right there.  Keep your credentials in a configuration file that is not part of your repository, and put it in `.gitignore` to avoid accidentally adding it.

Comment: Just to stress that you should never upload credentials to gibhub, not even for 5 minutes: there are bots that [continuously scan](http://www.devfactor.net/2014/12/30/2375-amazon-mistake/) for them, and (in case of Amazon keys) abuse them to mine bitcoins.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
# project/.gitignore

passwords.py

# project/passwords.py

GITHUB_KEY = '123'
GITHUB_KEY_SECRET = 'ABC'
GITHUB_TOKEN = '456'
GITHUB_TOKEN_SECRET = 'XYZ'

# project/my_script.py

from passwords import GITHUB_KEY, GITHUB_KEY_SECRET, GITHUB_TOKEN, GITHUB_TOKEN_SECRET

KEY = GITHUB_KEY
KEY_SECRET = GITHUB_KEY_SECRET
TOKEN = GITHUB_TOKEN
TOKEN_SECRET = GITHUB_TOKEN_SECRET
```

Comment: Not understand your idea... you mean when git commit, we change the secret key manually ?

Comment: No, you keep your passwords in a file that is not included in version control at all.  You keep that file out of version control by adding its path to '.gitignore.'  Then, when you need that password in your application, just import the variables that point to the password.

Comment: @liuzhidong - the meaning here is that the `passwords.py` file that contains the actual keys is not inserted into version control and hence is not viewable on github. You **will** need to ensure that this file exists since using `git checkout` will not create that file in a new location.

Comment: This will lead to error when deploying. `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.passwords'`

Comment: @patrickgerard That error is specific to your code. There's no reference to `app` in the given example.

Answer (score 2):

As hinted to by [@chishaku](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29056086/558021), a good idea would be to save all your confidential information in a separate file that is not version controlled ie: is not known by git. You do this by adding it to the `.gitignore` file.

With this in place, you can safely commit your code to GitHub where everyone can see your project - however your confidential information and passwords are no where to be seen!

Within your project, you can now read that file (or import it) and use the information held within.

Keep in mind that when you (or someone else) accesses this project, you will have to ensure that your "secret" file exists since your project depends on it.

In my projects, creating this "secret" file is part of the deploy script. Something like:

```
echo '{"password": "123"}' > config.json && git checkout master
```

This line of code writes the (simple) settings file to `config.json` and only afterwards retrieves the latest code version from the master branch.